# Chrome doesn't download archive files(zip)

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, zip

I'm working on a Vue.js project where users can download any files. Everything works fine, but for some reason, chrome doesn't download jar/zip files. There are any errors in chrome console. Moreover, it works on my local machine and doesn't work on production server. Here is vue.js code:

```
<a
  :href="file.path"
  target="_blank"
  class="icon-link block q-pr-xs"
>
  <q-icon name="get_app" size="sm"></q-icon>
</a>
```

and generated html

```
<a  data-v-52d0018a="" 
    href="http://myserver.com:9000/portal-fileuploader/static/file.rar" 
    target="_blank" 
    class="icon-link block q-pr-xs">
    
    <i  data-v-52d0018a="" 
        aria-hidden="true" 
        role="presentation" 
        class="material-icons q-icon notranslate">
        
        get_app
        
    </i>
</a>
```

I don't even know the direction of research, so will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Have you tried download attribute?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Result is the same, it works in my local machine and doesn't work in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Chrome 83 version, browser blocks downloading insecure files on HTTPS.

link: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5691978677223424